# Swift assert with string parameters

Tags: parameters, swift, assert

Why in Swift is this legal...

```
assert( false, "Unexpected diagnosis: \(diagnosis)" );
```

whereas this is not?

```
let assertString = "Unexpected diagnosis: \(diagnosis)"
assert( false, assertString );
```

In the second snippet, I get the error...

> Cannot invoke 'assert' with an argument list of type '(BooleanLiteralConvertible, String)

Surely, the second parameter is a string in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second paramter of assert is declared as either `message: @autoclosure () -> Str` or `_ message: StaticString`. I guess `"Unexpected diagnosis: \(diagnosis)"` is treated as expression and picked up by `@autoclosure`, while `assertString` is simply a `String` variable that cannot be converted to closure or `StaticString`.

`StaticString` can be made only with:

```
static func convertFromExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral(value: StaticString) -> StaticString
static func convertFromStringLiteral(value: StaticString) -> StaticString
```

I guess this explains why swift manual has note that you cannot use string interpolation in `assert()` as there is no support for `StringInterpolationConvertible`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks that's pretty heavy going for someone with < 24 hours experience in Swift. I guess it's side-effect of years of working in the 'pointer' world that this wasn't obvious to me.  Took some reading, by I understand it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

quote form documentations:

> ...(`assert()`) Performs a traditional C-style assert with an optional message.
>   Use this function for internal sanity checks that are active during testing but do not impact performance of shipping code. To check for invalid usage in Release builds, see `precondition(_:_:file:line:)`.

and i tested on Xcode 8, `precondition(_:_:file:line:)` works fine with formatted strings. e.g.:

```
precondition(userId.lengthOfBytes(using: .ascii) > 0, "\(userId) is invalid for DBManager.id")
```